# Android Studio - Layout Theme Selection -- Where is this data stored?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

I am quite familiar with Android layouts and the fact you can declare an app wide theme in the manifest or indirectly via the Styles resource such as `"Halo"`, or `"Material"`, etc... .

I also know that style can be done on a per layout basis. Android Studio "Layout Editor" even allows you to select a theme for the layout.

**Question:**

Where is the selected theme stored when applied per layout?

---

The [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles) seems to suggest its in the manifest where the activities are declared. For example:

```
<activity android:name=".MainMenu"  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"/>`
```

However, when I select a different theme, even after I compile and run the application I see no changes in  the manifest, or respective layout, or the Activity sub class.

So where is the association between a layout and the chosen theme for it being stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer to this question is that Android Studio does not currently modify anything when you select a layout in the preview, it is just a preview and that is it.

To make the change one has to manually edit the theme for the activity entry in the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

`AndroidManifest.xml` references `styles.xml` which in turns references `colors.xml`. The layout editor modifies `styles.xml`, you're *not* seeing the results because of possible overrides in `styles.xml`.

-- Modify the parent style in `styles.xml` and removes unwanted overrides within. --

---

After investigating this issue as I was also coming across this problem, here is the conclusion that I came to:

Starting with a new "Empty Activity" you will see the following in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`. That is not directly related to changes in the `Layout Editor` in the "Design View" of your current activity.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Hovering over the theme definition you will this below:

[image]

**styles.xml**

Clicking on it will take us to `styles.xml`. By default, you will see the following:

[image]

This is where `AppTheme` is coming from that is being referenced in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. As you see, `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` is the parent style, and if you want to change the overall theme you will need to modify that, e.g. `"@android:style/Theme.Material"` or `"@android:style/Theme.Holo"`.

It is worth noting that as long as the override colors are still there, you will not notice much changes when the app is launched, even though the changes did go through.

To see the changes commend the following lines:

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

By deleting or commenting:

```
<!--        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
```

**Theme Layout Editor**

For some reason Android Studio 2.2 got rid of the refresh button on the layout causing many difficulties in the update of the style.

For the time being, manually override the parent style in `styles.xml` and remove any overrides that are being imported from `colors.xml`. Not ideal, but it's a solution.

For a full list of themes you can check this developer [R.style](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme) link or by clicking on `Open Editor` to get a visual representation of the different themes.

[image]

Which displays the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding. I find that when I make changed to the parent theme of an activity in the WYSIWYG editor that none of the resource files are changed. It just seems for the benefit of presentation only. I know that one can manually force the parent theme for a layout by going to the activities manifest entry and using the theme attribute. Android studio does not modify that, nor styles.xml. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You are correct, it does not modify those since they're overridden by the user. I believe this concept is reinforced with their Material Design.